# Classification problem on potentially more than 1 labels

Tags: classification, deep-learning, convolution

I just started to learn Convolutional Neural Network, and like to predict a Pokémon type by its apperance (the input is image).

However, while many Pokémon has only one type, some Pokémon have two types (no Pokémon has more than 2 types). I'm not sure the proportion, but it is something like 60% for only one type vs 40% for two types, I guess.

In this case, how should I classify it? Should I mark all the output probability that has > 33% as predicted types, or is there anything better way? Also, is the convolutional neural network suitable in these cases?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification

Answer (score 0):

Convolutional networks are perfect for images. There are two realistic approaches to take with the problem. The first approach, which I think is the weaker of the two is to define every combination of types as a class. This will probably amount to around 50-70 classes which is quite a bit, depending on how many samples you have. Another disadvantage is that you don't get the synergy of having an (A, B) type as an example and another one that is an (A, C). By encoding them as two completely different classes you miss out on the overlap of type A. The other approach is to have a binary output for every type individually. Then you can use some threshold on the sigmoid output of each label to determine if it's that type or not. You can also use the knowledge that it will never have more than two types to not classify a pokemon as type C if A and B have higher activation values.

Answer (score 0):

For multi-label image classification, you want to make sure that your output activation is a sigmoid function (like Jan said) and train with one hot encoded labels for each of your images. For your specific problem, I would recommend adding a `None` label or choice so that each image doesn't need to have two types.

Here's a web page that could possibly help you understand and implement this:
https://suraj-deshmukh.github.io/Multi-Label-Image-Classification/